# Two Linux kernel modules corrupting a shared pointer - How to debug?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Suppose there are two `Linux kernel modules`.
There is one `global pointer` that is shared between these two modules.
`Module 1` is trying to access this `pointer`, corrupt this pointer value and exits.
Now `Module 2` is trying to access this `pointer`, which is no longer valid and crashes.

Module 1:

```
module_function()
{
     //corrupt global_ptr
}

module2_function()
{

    local_ptr = global_ptr;
    //local_ptr corrupted
    //Now if local_ptr is accessed, it will crash
}
```

Can somebody explain, if this scenario is valid and possible?
Then

i) How to debug this problem. That is, how to find out which module is corrupting the pointer?

ii) How to fix this problem so that module2 should never crash?

Comment: 0. Yes, that scenario is possible. 1. Try to catch modifications of the pointer. E.g., with breakpoints on data. 2. In general, there is no protection against the module functioning incorrectly. All modules and kernel core shares **single address space**. So not only global variables may be corrupted, but even local ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a classic case of `use-after-free` or `use-after-modify` kind of `bug` that generally causes `oops`, thus `tainting` the `linux kernel` with `G flag` set, resulting in `system hang and reboot`. You can observe these `logs` in `/var/log/kern.log` if you are not able to get `dmesg logs` due to `system hang`.
2. In order to debug such `kernel memory pointer corruption` issues, you need to `Enable Slab Corruption debug` in your `kernel menuconfig` and hence `.config`. For a quicker reference, the steps to do this are:- `make menuconfig ---> Kernel hacking ---> Memory debugging ---> Debug slab memory locations`
3. The design solution for this problem would be to not use `global pointers` between modules, because you never know which module might get `freed` first leading to pointer corruption.

Comment: Yes, I know about SLUB_DEBUG_ON. But I am not sure how this will help to find the real problem. It is possible to debug such problems using gdb?

Comment: When we enable the `Slab Debug On`, the kernel writes a known value `0x6A6A6A6A` into the memory regions which are `corrupted/freed`. Hence if your `global pointer` tries to access that `memory region`, it will eventually end up with the above value, which will be evident from your `dmesg logs`. I would also bet on putting the pointer to watch variable in gdb to debug such issues.